# 'Fail to take' interpretation

Tags: interpretation

> The skin graft failed to take.

What does 'take' do here?

What is the right way to interpret the verb 'take'?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The verb 'take' has lots of meanings, and not all are listed in every dictionary. The meaning in this sentence is 'have the effect or result that is desired'. If you dye some cloth with a dye that is wrong for the cloth, or incorrectly used, the colour may wash out, and we could say that the dye 'didn't take'. Also (for example) if we paint something with the wrong kind of paint, or use the wrong kind of glue to stick something to something else. As here, the skin graft did not stay where it was intended to.

> Take
>
> 41. VERB
>
> If something such as a drug or a dye takes, it has the effect or
> result that is intended.
>
> *If the cortisone doesn't take, I may have to have surgery.*
>
> Synonyms:
> work, succeed, do the trick [informal], have effect

[Take (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take)

Answer (score 27):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take)...

> **take** (intransitive verb)
> 3: to **establish a take** especially by uniting or growing
> *90 percent of the grafts take*

> **take** (noun)
> 4a: a local or systemic reaction indicative of successful vaccination (as against smallpox)
> 4b: a successful union (as of a graft)

In *most* contexts, this specific use of ***take*** can be understood as meaning *take **hold / root / effect*** (become firmly established / functional), but that doesn't imply the single-word intransitive usage is "short for" or "derived from" an underlying phrasal verb ***to take hold***. It's its own usage.

Answer (score 10):

More generally, I would say that the intransitive verb, "to take" has a meaning of "become established". It can be applied to an idea, a fad, a dye, a plant, an organ transplant, and so on - seemingly anywhere that a thing can either become established or be rejected.

Comment: I tried to give myself a cool nickname, but it didn't take.

Comment: @barbecue Indeed. Your current username sounds a little hot.